# Проблема со структурами

Tags: c++, c, функции, gcc, struct

Прошу помощи

Вот задание:
Создайте структуру Прямая с элементами x1, y1, x2, y2 – координаты двух точек, через которые проходит прямая. Для К заданных прямых вывести уравнение прямых в виде y=kx+b.

Проблема:
Ввожу координаты x1, x2, y1, y2, затем программа некорректно выводит уравнение(y=-nan(ind) * x + -nan(ind)).

Ниже код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct point
{
    double x1;
    double y1;
    double x2;
    double y2;
};

struct line
{
    double k;
    double b;
};

void scanxy(struct point lin, struct line ur)
{
    printf("Vvedite x1, y1: \n");
    scanf("%lf %lf", &lin.x1, &lin.y1);
    printf("Vvedite x2, y2: \n");
    scanf("%lf %lf", &lin.x2, &lin.y2);
}

struct line func(struct point lin)
{
    struct line ur;
    ur.k = (lin.y1 - lin.y2) / (lin.x1 - lin.x2);
    ur.b = lin.y2 - (ur.k * lin.x2);
    return ur;
}

void urav(struct point lin, struct line ur)
{
    ur = func(lin);
    printf("y = %lf * x + %lf\n", ur.k, ur.b);
}

int main()
{   
    struct point b = { 0, 0, 0, 0 }; 
    struct line a = {0, 0};
    int K;

    printf("Vvedite kol-vo pryamih: \n");
    scanf("%d", &K);

    for (int i = 0; i < K; i++)
    {
        printf("Pryamaya nomer %d\n", i + 1);
        scanxy(b, a);
        urav(b, a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Поскольку структуры передаются "по значению", функция `scanxy()` работает с *их копиями*.  Вам надо передавать в нее указатели на структуры.

Comment: Подскажите, как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

действительно, структура в функцию передаётся по значению. Это означает, что при вызове функции на стеке будет создана её копия, куда скопируются все поля изначальной структуры и, по завершению работы функции она удалится. Изначальная передаваемая структура затронута не будет. Для того, чтобы изменить передаваемую в функцию структуру, её надо передать по указателю:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct point
{
    double x1;
    double y1;
    double x2;
    double y2;
};

struct line
{
    double k;
    double b;
};

void scanxy(struct point *lin)
{
    printf("Vvedite x1, y1: \n");
    scanf("%lf %lf", &lin->x1, &lin->y1);
    printf("Vvedite x2, y2: \n");
    scanf("%lf %lf", &lin->x2, &lin->y2);
}

struct line func(struct point *lin, struct line *ur)
{
    ur->k = (lin->y1 - lin->y2) / (lin->x1 - lin->x2);
    ur->b = lin->y2 - (ur->k * lin->x2);
}

void urav(struct point *lin, struct line *ur)
{
    func(lin, ur);
    printf("y = %lf * x + %lf\n", ur->k, ur->b);
}

int main()
{   
    struct point b = {0}; 
    struct line a = {0};
    int K;

    printf("Vvedite kol-vo pryamih: \n");
    scanf("%d", &K);

    for (int i = 0; i < K; i++)
    {
        printf("Pryamaya nomer %d\n", i + 1);
        scanxy(&b);
        urav(&b, &a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Примечания к коду:

1) При создании структуры в main, нет необходимость обнулять каждое поле, достаточно обнулить первое {0}, остальные поля обнуляться автоматически.

2) Адрес структуры можно получить так: **&a**, в функции принимается указатель на структуру так: **struct line *a**. Если ты работаешь с указателем на структуру, то доступ к элементам осуществляется с помощью **->** а не точки.

3) Не понятно, зачем в изначальном коде ты передавал в функцию **scanxy** структуру ur.

Comment: Спасибо большое, плохо понимаю указатели и адреса